# Have SharePoint 2010 display a list into multiple columns on one page, instead of a new page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I'm fairly new to SharePoint 2010.  I've been tasked with displaying all of our company's forms on one page.   I can do it using web parts (i.e. one for each department), however some departments have more forms than others and it makes it difficult to line it up and keep each column even on the page.
So instead i tried using the basic list view (Webpart).  I get all of the forms down the page in one column. This ends up being about 3 pages, with a lot of wasted white space.  What I would like to do would be to have it list down until the bottom of the page in one column, and then continue in another column.  I'm thinking 2 or 3 columns would probably be enough to display them properly on one page.  My thinking is it would be similar to dividing a page in Word 2010 into 2 or 3 columns. Is this possible, or would some coding be needed to accomplish this?  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

no this would require heavy coding, by heavy i mean fully coded webpart todo what your asking for.

Usually people would just settle for pageing like 1 of 10 within the webpart. I presume thats what you dont want?

would it be too much to not have paging but rather show all content, it would mean a bit of scrolling todo if each column is long.

so what im trying to say is the data view webpart your talking about i presume is showing large lists in pages with a max row count, once reached a new page is created. I preposing not to use list view webpart but rather a content query webpart

https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Display-data-from-multiple-lists-with-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-d560f477-8fc1-4258-aeb2-70aa932e07da

within the CQWP you can go into its properties and change it so that when you edit the webpart you should see an option: "Limit the number of items to display" , make sure its unchecked and it will display all content on one page. Use the Query part to fine tune the results and also there are other settings available to make it look more appealing, for further info look here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2006/10/25/configuring-and-customizing-the-content-query-web-part.aspx

also to clarify, when you say all forms you mean all rows? also how many columns are there and how many records you want to display. Im confused as you say you display it on one page but then state that its 3 pages worth? if its so huge you should have paging enabled as that is the correct way if its approx 3 pages long on one page to display? set the properties of the webpart to enable paging and set the ammount to 35 items per view and see the result! also can you clarify what a form is? do you mean a row (item) as form in sharepoint is an aspx page where you can add data like itemAdding.aspx to add items to a list.

Comment: thanks so much for responding.  I wanted to clarify.   Currently our page layout has 3 web part zones :left, middle, right. My list is just a document library with all of the forms (pdfs) for all departments.  I am able to fit everything on one page by using a web part for each department to list its documents, some departments in the left zone, some and the middle zone, etc. This allows me to fit everything on one page, though it isnt exactly pretty. However, doing it in this manner (all in one web part) is what makes it 3 pages long.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I don't like the CQWP... I would try to favor a search based approach. For this you need to be able to identify those forms via search if possible. If you cant identify via a managed property, and have to result to a bunch of "Or's" for the different path's the performance gain might not be there...

Answer (score 0):

If your happy lining them up yourself and making changes every now and again when new forms are preset you could do the below.

Use the IDs of the forms as filters.  Use your filters and IDs to limit the amount showing in each column.  So first column might filter to IDs 1-5, second column 6-10. third 11-15 etc.  It will take a little bit of playing to get it right but it will work.  If you are using the app part you will need to create views or inset filter web parts onto the page to send values to the web parts.  If you use the CQWP you will be able to filter by the IDs.  Call it a fast and dirty if you will but it will be effective :)